# Show/hide button in ruby with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problems with my button used to hide then show a form with jQuery.  I put a path to signup in the button to get the button to show up and work, and now I know that the form is showing when I click the button.  But then it directs to the signup path like it should.  I need to figure out how to get the button to work without a path included, just functioning as a show/hide.

If I remove the path, it will not work.

**home.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Add Car", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>

<section class="car_form">
  <%= render 'shared/car_form' %>
</section>
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">     
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.car_form').hide(); //form id
        $('.btn-primary').click(function() { // button id
         $('.car_form').show(); //form id
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: @loanburger he provided html actually... And his JQ is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to mention the signup_path in the button, otherwise you could do it:

`<%= link_to "Add Car", 'javascript:void(0)', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>`